# `README` badges not getting rendered properly in `pkgdown` website

Tags: r, pkgdown

I have thus far created 6 different `pkgdown` websites for my R packages (e.g., [ggstatsplot](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ggstatsplot/), [kittyR](https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/kittyR/), etc.) and none of them ever had the following issue.

For the first time, running the following command

```r
pkgdown::build_site(
  lazy = FALSE,
  run_dont_run = TRUE,
  seed = 123,
  devel = TRUE
)
```

is not rendering `README` badges and I am not sure why since the `yaml` I am using is similar to my other packages. I had raised [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/1207) on `pkgdown` GitHub repo, but it didn't help.

More explicitly, here is what my `README` looks like-

- README: https://github.com/IndrajeetPatil/ipmisc/blob/master/README.md

[image]

And here is what the `pkgdown` output looks like-

- pkgdown: https://indrajeetpatil.github.io/ipmisc/

[image: ![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/11330453/72661380-76ada780-39d9-11ea-8897-b7e991deabb8.png)]

I get no warnings or errors while building the website., but as can be seen here, the badges are not rendered at all on the homepage. Any ideas on why this might be happening or how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: replicated this behavior on a different package using your README file with latest dev version of `pkgdown`. I noticed that adding something (anything) in backticks before the first heading made the badges re-appear. Have no idea why but may help pkgdown developers understand and be a workaround for you. Try adding the word "test" in backticks at line 16 of your README.Rmd file.

Comment: Thanks for the astute observation! That workaround indeed solves the issue :)
Can you post the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue with the README file you linked. I noticed that adding text (any characters) in backticks before the first heading made the badges re-appear. The reason has to do with how `pkgdown` parses the readme to look for badges. As a workaround, you could try adding the word "test" in backticks at line 16 of your README.Rmd file.

This seems to have now been resolved in the dev version of `pkgdown`. See the discussion of the [issue](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/issues/1207) for more details and consider using `<!-- badges: start -->` and `<!-- badges: end -->` around the badges section.